# Access angular "in loop" variables from plain, inline, javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, morris.js

Im inside a loop, let's say

```
<div ng-repeat="median in medians">...</div>
```

The value of median is (stripped)

```
    {  
       "0":{  
          "year":"2013",
          "company":"58.10",
          "median":102,
          "suffix":" %"
       },
       "1":{  
          "year":"2012",
          "company":"30.70",
          "median":79.1,
          "suffix":" %"
       }
    }
```

Now, I want to use these values for a chart with MorrisJS. In order to do so, i would need to transform it and access it through regular javascript. Transformation is no problem, but how do i access median (as opposed to medianS that could simple be done with something like

```
$("[ng-controller=SomeController").scope().medians
```

?

What i need to produce is something like this (obv. tested and not working):

```
    var originalData = {{ median }}; //can not reach this, because i dont know at which index we're on

    // create/format a correct array of data (real data is more complex)
    var years = [];
    for (var year in median)
    {
        years.push({
            year: year.year,
            company: year.company
        });
    }

    new Morris.Line({
      element: "chart-for-" + {{ median.year }}, //need to find element
      data: years, //use the produced array
      xkey: 'year',
      ykeys: ['company'],
      labels: ['Company Value']
    });
```

How can I reach this very value? Or, is there any better/more angular way of doing these things?

Comment: Have you got a working controller and view containing your ng-repeat?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I show an table with the `median`data, but want to give user the possibility to show data as a chart as well. The problem is simply accessing the (temp) variable median which scope is "in the loop".

Comment: You need to initialize things like this in directives where the element itself is exposed

Comment: i agree with @charlietfl, directive is always the best approach when you want to use jquery in angularjs. However if you want to know how to access the median that you are searching for, you can find it by analysing my answer and creating the directive method to achieve it.